How to use iopen pyxl in C#?
Im creating a Windows Forms Project based on C# using python scripts. But when click the button, which should start a python script i have an error "No module named 'openpyxl'"
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter("TxtData.txt", false);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    fs.WriteLine(today);
                }
                else
                {
                    fs.WriteLine(data[i]);
                }
            }

            fs.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Saved");

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            engine.ExecuteFile("MainData.py", scope); //Right here
            dynamic load_mas = scope.GetVariable("load_mas");
            dynamic saved = load_mas();
        }

And this is my ython code:
from openpyxl import load_workbook

Pydata = [" ", " ", " ", " ", "Нет данных", "Нет данных", " ", " ", " ",]
# 1 - Справ№, 2 - Рев, 3 - Дата, 4 - Заказчик, 5 - Потребитель, 6 - Проект, 7 - Установка, 8 - Проектант

helper = 7

def load_mas():
    with open('TxtData.txt') as f:
        for i in range(0, 9):
            Pydata[i] = f.readline()

def save_table():
    wb = load_workbook(filename = r'C:\Users\Elisey Kartavyy\Documents\Школа\ООП\Visual Studio\NTVALVE\Shablon.xlsx', data_only = True)
    sheet = wb['Лист1']
    for i in range(len(Pydata)):
        index = 'D' + str(helper)
        sheet[index].value = Pydata[i]
        helper += 1
    wb.save('Shablon.xlsx')

Ive alredy installed openpyxl using pip and IronPython into the Visual Studio 2020

Based on my test, I reproduced the same problem with you. We need to set search paths for the libraries we want to use.
Please try the following code:
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
 var scope = engine.CreateScope();
 ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
 searchPaths.Add("C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 3.4\\Lib");
 searchPaths.Add("C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 3.4\\Lib\\site-packages");
 engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
 engine.ExecuteFile("MainData.py", scope); //Right here

Note: I find the openpyxl in the following path:

